# Specify node-fetch to get JSON

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to specify node-fetch to request for JSON for a GET request? The external api endpoint I'm trying to reach sends back xml.

I know I can do something like this on the front-end, but can I do this in my node-server?

```
const response = fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  }
});
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.get('/buses/location', (req, res) => {
  const apiURL = `${TRANSLINK_URL}${TRANSLINK_TOKEN}`

  fetch(apiURL)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
         response.json()
         .then((data) => {
             res.json(data)
         })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      }
      else {
        res.sendStatus(response.status)
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
})
```

Comment: First you have no headers in your request `fetch('https://ulsterbus.co.uk/', {
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/xml' },
    })`

Comment: Second if you expect xml to be returned as is in your question then res.json will throw an error

Comment: Third your express route is using a callback but your response is returning a promise. You will need to choose one or the other; Promises or callbacks?

Comment: What do you mean by choosing between call back or promises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code include the application/json request header and it is refactored with [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await), you should use that instead of callbacks

```js
app.get('/buses/location', async (req, res) => {
  const apiURL = `${TRANSLINK_URL}${TRANSLINK_TOKEN}`;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiURL, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }});
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    res.send(jsonResponse);
  }
  catch (e){
    console.log(e);
  }
})
```

However, the server you are reaching must support json responses when requested, otherwise you will have to manage your data as xml

Comment: Instead of 'Content-Type' in the header, I had to use 'Accept'. What is the difference?

Comment: That was a little mistake that i made, you should use `Accept` in this case =)